# How do I push a VC from a push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification

I receive a push which has an id of an object I need to look up. I save this to the app delegate.

In my main view controller, I fetch an index of all the objects.

I check if my app delegate has an id saved. If it does, I scan the objects I fetched from the index and push a detail view controller with that object.

The new view controller doesn't function properly and crashes when I tap back. Research indicated this is because my VC had a nil frame.

What's a good workflow for pushing a detail VC from a push?

Comment: mind sharing some code please ?

Answer (score 0):

With the information you have provided seems to be there is something wrong with your design.

Normally your user has a flow in navigation controller (1-2-3-4-5) and reaches to a point. 
What you might be trying to do is (1-5) and when the user comes back it crashes because it haven't been able to create that state back. If this is the case there is something wrong with your design.

You can't push 5th element directly to a stack (a nav controller is a stack) without pushing first four. Reuse the code, trace the path normally user follows to create that state back.